# Am I missing a step with using Features?

Tags: 7, panels, features

I've made changes to a Panel variant on my local site and wish to push it to the remote site, but I am having trouble doing this - the changes to the variant are not appearing on my remote site.

Here's what I am doing:

1. In Features I find the Page Manger section with my variants. I check them all, increment the version number and hit download.
2. I unzip the downloaded .tar file and place the Feature files within my folder structure: modules>>features>>module_name. I overwrite the existing files in there.
3. Using Git, I push these to my remote site (all's good with this step - I see the CSS changes I pushed as well)
4. On the remote site I access features and see that my module's features are overwritten. I check it's check box and hit Save Settings.

But nothing changes when I look at my variants - my changes do not appear.

Is there a step I am missing here?

Comment: Do your features go from "overridden" to "default"?

Comment: @lukedekker No they dont

Comment: In step 4, do you see the new version number under the feature?

Comment: @longboardnode on the remote site? Yes I do

Comment: Inspect the Feature's .info and the .pages_default.inc files on your local to see if the variant ID/UUID is the same as on your remote. Sometimes when Features tries to add new variants the system assigns the variants new IDs and then everything gets out of whack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Features can sometimes be finicky. Often times, just clearing caches after reverting will cause your changes to go into effect. In other cases, it can be necessary to revert the specific item (such as views or rules).

Personally, I haven't used Page Manager with features, but the general concepts apply consistently across the board.